# Redirect to another page PHP

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink

what i should do to redirect to another page? what i have in comments are failed tries.

```
case 6:
            //$redirectLocation = "http://www.productionportugal.com/blog";
          //  header'Location: ' . $redirectLocation); assume it like homepage

            //include '/blog/index.php';
            //include 'blog/index.php'; database error

            //ini_set('include_path', '/blog');
            //set_include_path('/blog');

          // include_path=".:/blog" white page
           // include="/blog/index.php"

         //   $redirectLocation = "http://www.productionportugal.com/blog";


                require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Blog.php';

                $_blog = new Blog();

                $menuL = $_blog->getMenu();

                $conteudo = "<div class='container' id='blogMenu'>
                                <div class='titulo'>$nome
                                <div class='btn-group'>
                                    <a href='#' data-toggle='dropdown' id='dropdownBlog'>
                                      <span class='caret'></span>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class='dropdown-menu' aria-labelledby='dropdownBlog' role='menu'>
                                      $menuL
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <a class='sprite leftS' id='prevLatestBlog'></a><a class='sprite rightS' id='nextLatestBlog'></a></div>
                            </div>";
                $conteudo .= $_blog->getALL();

            break;
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
header("Location: ".$website);
```

to redirect to other pages.

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

**Edit:** After you explain that you want a button that will do it onclick.

You can add this code:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.productionportugal.com/blog";
```

to the button onclick command to redirect when you click on button.

Comment: i tried this but it assues the fuction like the home page $website = "http://www.productionportugal.com/blog";
header("Location: ".$website);

Comment: try to write it like this: header('Location: http://www.productionportugal.com/blog'); what error do you get?

Comment: it will assume the link like a homepage, all i want is press a button and go to external page.

Comment: you can try to solve it in JS. add this code in oclick to your link: window.location.href = "productionportugal.com/blog".

Comment: i dont have it in this page

Comment: if i post all code of the page menus.php can you help me? please

Answer (score 0):

You send a header, with your destination `url`.

```
<?php
$newUrl = "http://www.productionportugal.com/blog";
header('Location: '.$newURL);
?>
```

It's as easy as that.

**Note** it will give an error if the headers are already send. Here is a detailed answer to how that works: [headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/5120280)

Comment: Than your `url` is simply a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly than the below code will help:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

You can submit any url

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Also please note that header must appear in code before any output

Comment: it will assume the link like a homepage, all i want is press a button and go to external page..

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.
When pressing the button, the url will open as a new tab, without closing the current page you pressed the button on.

```
<!--HTML--> 
<button type="submit" onclick="openExt('URL GOES IN HERE')"></button>

<!--JavaScript--> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function openExt(url) {
    window.open(url, "_blank"); 
} 
</script>
```